# AD and Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, webforms, active-directory, forms-authentication

I'm trying to allow users to login with either forms authentication or their AD account but having some problems. I'm logged into an AD accountno,w but `Page.User.Identity.Name` is blank. I have this in my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://full.domain.address:389/DC=mydomain,DC=blah,DC=uk"/>
    <add name="myapp" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=myapp;User ID=myapp;Password=myapp" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="129600" name="CookieMonster" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="myapp" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="myapp" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
```

Do I need to do something else to get this to work? I've tried logging in with my domain account and domain\myaccount to no avail.

When I try `var u = Membership.GetUser("mydomain\\myuser");` I get an error: Usernames must not contain '\' when mapped to 'userPrincipalName'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD `userPrincipalName` might be something like `user@full.domain.address`. Try using the `sAMAccountName` value for the `attributeMapUsername`:

```
<add name="ADMembershipProvider" 
  type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
  connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
  attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
```

If you are unable to connect, you may need to add `connectionUsername` and `connectionUserPassword` attributes (check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx) documentation).

Comment: That's not an attribute I noticed in any of the articles I read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"sAMAccountName" does not include the domain. To resolve your problem, simply remove the domain qualifying form your username:

Instead of `var u = Membership.GetUser("mydomain\\myuser");`

use `var u = Membership.GetUser("myuser");`

This is because you specified the domain in the connection string, implicitly by connecting to a particular active directory.